# Data in hive giving different data when inserted into a table and queries directly

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am working on Hive version 2.3.8.

There is a table which is getting data directly from the S3 location on AWS. When I am using this table to insert it into an temporary ORC table, incorrect data is stored.

But the same query without inserting in a table will give the correct data.

There is no join on the table.

At last I am fetching data directly, but that is not efficient since the data is required in more than 2-3 places. This is increasing the turnaround time for my query

As asked:
Let the dump be like

```
col1 col2     col3  
a    1st jan  1st jan  
a    1st jan  2nd jan                      
a    1st jan  3rd jan
```

When I am inserting into a table:

```
col1 col2     col3
a    1st jan  1st jan
a    1st jan  2nd jan
a    1st jan  3rd jan
a    1st jan  4th jan
a    1st jan  5th jan
```

And if queries directly from the dump:

```
col1 col2     col3  
a    1st jan  1st jan  
a    1st jan  2nd jan                      
a    1st jan  3rd jan
```

While inserting even if I create a completely new table with a very weird name that can never be present with ghost data, I am still getting the same result.

Comment: Please show an example of your queries and the results you get vs expect

Comment: Added the example

Comment: Thanks, but that's just data, not any query you're using. Please show those and the table definition as well